# Does the shortcut in DR2:OTR persist across a new game?

Tags: dead-rising-2-off-the-record

I just got the shortcut from the mall to Royal Flush Plaza in DR2:OTR. If I start a new game with this save, will I still know the shortcut? Or do I have to wait until that Survivor pops up and rescue her again? Sorry if this is easy, my google-fu was not working.